# ERROR java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

After executing the query count (*), I get an unexpected error. I fulfilled this request using a workbanch graphical interface, everything is fine there. In my code, an error occurs. I can not understand the reason.

Here is the entity manager that performs my work with the database:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private val entityManager: EntityManager? = null

    fun count(request: HttpServletRequest): Int {
        val query = entityManager!!.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resume r", Resume::class.java)
        return (query.getSingleResult() as Number).toInt()
    }
```

This is a class the amount of which you need to get:

```
@Entity
@ValidWorkType
@ValidProfField
@ValidEducation
@ValidAddress
@ValidDescResume
data class Resume (

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long? = null,

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        var user: User? = null,

        var datecreate: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),

        @get:Size(min = 1, max = 60, message = "{error.work.profession}")
        var profession: String? = null,

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
        @get:Valid
        var numberPhone: NumberPhone? = null,

        @get:Email(message = "{text.error.user.email}")
        @get:Size(min = 1, max = 100, message = "{text.error.user.email.size}")
        var email: String? = null,

        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE])
        @get:NotNull(message = "{error.work.prof.field}")
        override var profField: ProfField? = null,

        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE])
        @get:NotNull(message = "{error.work.work.type}")
        override var workType: WorkType? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
        @get:Valid
        var wage: Wage? = null,

        @ManyToOne
        override var education: Education? = null,

        var experience: Int? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        @get:Valid
        override var description: DescriptionResume? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
        override var address: Address? = null,

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
        var photo: ContainerSquareImages? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
        var views: Views = Views(),

        @Transient
        var rating: Int? = null

): ParentWorkType, ParentProfField, ParentEducation, ParentAddress, ParentDescResume {

        fun getPeriodExperience(): Period? {
                if (experience!=null) {
                        return Period.between(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(experience!!.toLong()))
                } else { return null }
        }

        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
                if (this === other) return true
                if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

                other as Resume

                if (user != other.user) return false
                if (profession != other.profession) return false
                if (numberPhone != other.numberPhone) return false
                if (email != other.email) return false
                if (profField != other.profField) return false
                if (workType != other.workType) return false
                if (wage != other.wage) return false
                if (education != other.education) return false
                if (experience != other.experience) return false
                if (description != other.description) return false
                if (address != other.address) return false

                return true
        }

        override fun hashCode(): Int {
                var result = user?.hashCode() ?: 0
                result = 31 * result + (profession?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (numberPhone?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (email?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (profField?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (workType?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (wage?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (education?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (experience?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (description?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                result = 31 * result + (address?.hashCode() ?: 0)
                return result
        }

        fun getYearsCalendar() {

        }

        companion object {
                const val NAME_PARAM = "resume"
        }
}
```

Here is the error log itself can not understand why, and why, please help:

```
Hibernate: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resume r
[WARN ] 2019-07-01 00:37:08.485 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
[ERROR] 2019-07-01 00:37:08.485 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'id' not found.
[ERROR] 2019-07-01 00:37:08.525 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:581) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:928) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
```

Comment: Do you get this error without the count. Meaning just a plan select all.  Or try putting a single field in the count statment.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging for Hibernate and show what the executed statement is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using JPQL:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private val entityManager: EntityManager? = null

    fun count(request: HttpServletRequest): Long {
        val query = entityManager!!.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(resume.id) FROM Resume resume")
        return query.singleResult as Long
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The doc for createNativeQuery reads :

> Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString,
>                           Class resultClass)
>
> sqlString - a native SQL query string
>
> resultClass - the class of the resulting instance(s)

Your query is :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resume r
```

That is accessing the `resume` table, but it is returning an Integer - not a `resume` instance.  That's why you are getting the `Column 'id' not found.`.

<s>The fix is simply to pass Integer as the result class, so :</s>

val query = entityManager!!.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resume r", Integer::class.java)

Since scalars are not mapped, the fix is to not pass a result class, so :

```
val query = entityManager!!.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resume r")
```

Comment: not work - org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer

Comment: Apologies, Scalars are not mapped, so no mapping class should be being passed.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With The javax.persistence.Query JPA interface : choose NamedQuery or TypedQuery

Example

```
@javax.persistence.NamedQuery(
    name="resumeCountTest", query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resume r")
    public class Resume {
 -------------
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("resumeCountTest");
long resumeCount = query.getSingleResult();
return resumeCount ;
```

More informations [Running JPA Queries](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute)

Comment: need create dinamic query